# Error while running spring-boot application. Invocation Target Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I run my spring-boot app i get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project nlp-pipeline-svc: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
```

Full Trace Error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run 
(AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
at 
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Bindable.withExistingValue 
(Bindable.java:162)
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Bindable.ofInstance 
(Bindable.java:192)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.bindToSpringApplication 
(SpringApplication.java:545)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment 
(SpringApplication.java:359)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run 
(SpringApplication.java:317)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run 
(SpringApplication.java:1255)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run 
(SpringApplication.java:1243)
at com.sap.health.nlp.pipeline.NLPPipelineSvcApplication.main 
(NLPPipelineSvcApplication.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run 
(AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using spring 2.0.3 version. and java version of 1.8
Can anyone please help. I am not able to find if there is any dependency conflict in the spring versions.

Comment: Can you show` ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;`?

Comment: It is an in-built functional interface introduced in java 8.